# Python Pandas - Splitting strings to columns (series to dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple question. Here it is:
I have a pandas series of strings:

```
In [54]: import pandas as pd

In [55]: pd.Series(["01234", "asdfg"])
Out[55]: 
0    01234
1    asdfg
dtype: object
```

What I need is a dataframe that has a column for every position of the strings. All strings have equal lengths.

```
Out[55]:
    0   1   2   3   4
0   '0' '1' '2' '3' '4'
1   'a' 's' 'd' 'f' 'g'
```

Can you please help me?
I've tried all sorts of string operations...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Series `s` constructed:

```
df = s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
```

If you're starting from the raw data, it'd probably be easier to just go directly to a DataFrame:

```
data = ["01234", "asdfg"]
df = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in data])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will test yours and the above solution for performance! :)

Comment: After some time computing, IPython states very unspecifically: "The kernel seems to have died."

Answer (score 0):

If you have a NumPy array of string dtype:

```
In [22]: arr
Out[22]: 
array(['01234', 'asdfg'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

then you can view it as an array of dtype `'S1'` to split each string into 1-byte characters:

```
In [23]: arr.view('S1')
Out[23]: 
array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

and then reshape it to obtain the desired form:

```
In [24]: arr.view('S1').reshape(2, -1)
Out[24]: 
array([['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
       ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Therefore,

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["01234", "asdfg"])
n = len(s[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(s.values
                  .astype('S{}'.format(n))
                  .view('S1')
                  .reshape(len(s), -1))

print(df)
```

yields

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  a  s  d  f  g
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I get my data from a msgpack.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "all strings have equal lengths", I would use [pandas.Series.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) function for that:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["01234", "asdfg"])
print('Original series:\n', s)

re_pat = ''.join(['(?P<col{0}>.)'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(s[0]) +1)])
print('\nRegEx for s.str.extract():\t{0}'.format(re_pat))

df = s.str.extract(re_pat)
print('\nresulting DF:\n', df)
```

Output:

```
Original series:
 0    01234
1    asdfg
dtype: object

RegEx for s.str.extract():
 (?P<col1>.)(?P<col2>.)(?P<col3>.)(?P<col4>.)(?P<col5>.)

resulting DF:
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0    0    1    2    3    4
1    a    s    d    f    g
```

PS of course, you don't have to name your columns explicitly:

```
re_pat = '(.)' * len(s[0])
print('\nRegEx for s.str.extract():\t{0}'.format(re_pat))

df = s.str.extract(re_pat)
print('\nresulting DF:\n', df)
```

Output:

```
resulting DF:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  a  s  d  f  g
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!

Comment: You welcome! Please feel free to accept the answer which was the most helpful for you - this might help others who has same or similar issues in future!

Comment: Hi! Just now I found the time to try your answer.

Sadly, IPython throws this error.

/home/david/libraries/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc in compile(p, flags)
    581     if p.pattern.groups > 100:
    582         raise AssertionError(
--> 583             "sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"
    584             )
    585 

AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups

The number of columns aimed at is 10000, looks like regex won't solve this problem :/